# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException thrown when adding to List

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

When I run this,  I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` despite me using `iterator.remove();`

it's obviously me adding the number 6 in the loop. Does this happen because the iterator "doesn't know" it's there and is there anyway to fix it?

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");

    for(Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();it.hasNext();){
        String value = it.next();

        if(value.equals("4")) {
            it.remove();
            list.add("6");
        }

        System.out.println("List Value:"+value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`ConcurrentModificationException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) is thrown when calling `String value = it.next();`. But the actual culprit is `list.add("6");`. You mustn't modify a `Collection` while iterating over it directly. You are using `it.remove();` which is fine, but not `list.add("6");`.

While you can solve the problem with `Stream`s, I will first offer a solution with `Iterator`s, as this is a good first step for understanding the problem.

You need a [`ListIterator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) if you want to add and remove during iteration:

```
for (ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();){
    String value = it.next();

    if (value.equals("4")) {
        it.remove();
        it.add("6");
    }

    System.out.println("List Value: " + value);
}
```

This should do the trick!

---

A solution using `Stream`s:

```
List<String> newList = list.stream()
        .map(s -> s.equals("4") ? "6" : s)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here we create a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) from your `List`. We `map` all values to themselves, only `"4"` gets mapped to `"6"` and then we collect it back into a `List`. But caution, `newList` is immutable!

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is a very common exception when working with java collection classes. Java `Collection` classes are fail-fast, which means if the `Collection` will be changed while some thread is traversing over it using iterator, the 
`iterator.next()` will `throw ConcurrentModificationException`.
Concurrent modification exception can come in case of multithreaded as well as single threaded java programming environment.