# Concurrent modification of two Set<String> by retainAll

Tags: java

I need some how to modify set during iteration by retainAll

Let's say I have next code:

```java
set.forEach(it - > {
    set.retainAll(someMapWithSets.get(it))
});
```

I've tried approach with iterators:

```java
for (Iterator<String> iterator = set.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String value = iterator.next();
    set.retainAll(someMapWithSets.get(value))
}
```

It did not work. `ConcurrentModificationException` was thrown.

How to do that correctly?

Update.

Whole task is the next:

I have set

```
{A,B,C}
```

And I have map of sets which indicates if elements are compatible:

```
A: B,C - (means A is compatible with B and C and etc) 
B: A,E,C
C: A,B
```

I need to have map of sets where all possible combinations of compatible elements are present:

```
A,B,C
```

So as I part of solution I thought I could create method that retains only compatible elements for the given set and chosen element.

```
 public static Set<String> define(Set<String> elements, String rootElement) {
        Set<String> result = someMapWithElements.get(rootElement);
        result.retainAll(elements);
        result.add(rootElement);
        result.forEach(it -> result.retainAll(someMapWithElements.get(it)))
        return result;
    }
```

But obviously I get `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Modifying a set while another function is working on it is a breach of contract; why do you want do this? Can you specify exactly how you're trying to modify the set? There may be a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException thrown when adding to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49971932/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-when-adding-to-list)

Comment: You have to use the `Iterator` for any operations on the collection while iterating or you will get the `ConcurrentModificationException`. Basically you can't use `retainAll()`. Consider using streams instead.

Comment: Hi @dominicm00 ! I've updated my question with details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a set using the `retainAll` method while iterating over that same object. Therefore you will need to create a new set (or other collection) to use as an iteration variable, like:

```
new HashSet(set).forEach(it - > {
    set.retainAll(someMapWithSets.get(it))
});
```

`HashSet` can be replaced by `TreeSet` or any other set object that is suitable.

If actually need to change the set while iterating, you will need to use the `remove` method in `Iterator`.

Comment: "You cannot change a set while iterating over that same object" Wrong. "Iterators allow the caller to remove elements from the underlying collection during the iteration with well-defined semantics" [Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)

Comment: Ok, you cannot change it in this way. Still the answer is an answer that I think works. Using the remove method in Iterator is not an answer to the original question, as that would imply re-implementing retainAll manually.

Comment: I think you're reimplementing Java streams.

Comment: Probably providing an answer with your view would be the best way to help then